# Select in one to many

Tags: sql

I have Student S table and Tests T table with one to many relation from S to T.

T has a boolean field "passed", I want to get a list of all students that failed all the tests.

Comment: And? I'd suggest a JOIN.

Comment: A good place to start is with `SELECT`.  Assuming that your data is in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `studentid` field in both `s` and `t` tables:

```
select * from s 
where not exists (select * from t where t.studentid = s.studentid and t.passed = 1)
```

Comment: seemed to work but when i added a join with another table and a condition on a field of the table i joined it seems to give wrong results with respects to the passed condition, any idea why?

Comment: Not without any more info, sorry... I suggest you accept this answer and create another question with more information.

Comment: @LuísChaves I tested it in a small example, where is the problem in your opinion?

Comment: Sorry... I mistake myseft in the browser windows... That comment was for another awnser..my deep apologies

Comment: No worries, but try to be more specific in your comments... "This code is wrong" is hardly a useful comment without more info, don't you think?

Comment: I agree with you... Once again my apologies